# XNA draw order issues

Tags: c#, xna, rendering

I've been trying to apply a desaturation and white noise effect to my XNA project, and I've managed to do it but now I'm encountering some issues with the draw order.

In the code below, the commented out lines are what is causing the issue. If they are commented, the draw order problem is fixed, but then the screen isn't desaturated. When they're uncommented, the screen is desatured as I wish but the draw order problem occurs.

```
//GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(scaleupTarget);
GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.SeaGreen);            

DrawModel(building_a_mdl, (Matrix.Identity * Matrix.CreateTranslation(100, -14, -100)), building_a_tex);

/*GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
scaleupEffect.Parameters["RandomOffset"].SetValue((float)rng.NextDouble());
GraphicsDevice.Textures[1] = noiseTexture;
spriteBatch.Begin(
    SpriteSortMode.Texture,
    BlendState.AlphaBlend,
    SamplerState.PointClamp,
    null,
    null,
    scaleupEffect);
spriteBatch.Draw(scaleupTarget, Vector2.Zero, null, Color.White, 0.0f, Vector2.Zero, upScaleAmount, SpriteEffects.None, 0.0f);
spriteBatch.End();*/
```

[image: With the issue]

[image: With the issue]

Comment: What exactly isn't drawing correctly? Have you tried changing the BlendState when you call SpriteBatch.Begin()?

Comment: @davidsbro If you look closely on the black and white image (it's hard to see) but you can see windows from the other side of the building being rendered through it - a set of bars running across the model. I've changed the BlendState, SpriteSortMode and SamplerState, all with no luck.

Comment: @JamesMonger Have you change DepthStencialState and RasterizerState before drawing model?

Comment: @Blau I changed DepthStencilState but with no luck - I didn't change RasterizerState.

Comment: Why don't you try setting 'GraphicsDevice.RenderState.DepthBufferEnable = true' the line before you draw your 3d models. I just remembered I had the same problem you did, and setting this to true before each draw fixed the problem.

Comment: @davidsbro I get an error: `'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.GraphicsDevice' does not contain a definition for 'RenderState' and no extension method 'RenderState' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.GraphicsDevice' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`. I think that was deprecated in XNA 4.0

Comment: Since you are using XNA 4.0, instead of `GraphicsDevice.RenderState.DepthBufferEnable = true`, try this `DepthStencilState depthBufferState = new DepthStencilState(); 
depthBufferState.DepthBufferEnable = true;
GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = depthBufferState;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
    RenderTarget2D scaleupTarget = null;

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {                        
            if (scaleupTarget == null)
            {
                    // be sure to keep the depthformat when creating the new renderTarget2d
                    scaleupTarget = new RenderTarget2D(GraphicsDevice, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height, false, SurfaceFormat.Color, DepthFormat.Depth24);                
            }        
            GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(scaleupTarget);
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(ClearOptions.Target, Color.SeaGreen, 1.0f, 0);
            GraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.Opaque;
            GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;

            // Setup the rasterState, 
            // if CullMode.None; works, try with 
            // CullMode.CullCounterClockwiseFace
            // afterwards
            var rs = new RasterizerState();
            rs.CullMode = CullMode.None;
            rs.FillMode = FillMode.Solid;

            // Set the GraphicsDevice to use the new RasterizeState
            GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = rs;

            DrawModel(building_a_mdl, (Matrix.Identity * Matrix.CreateTranslation(100, -14, -100)), building_a_tex);

            scaleupEffect.Parameters["RandomOffset"].SetValue((float)rng.NextDouble());
            GraphicsDevice.Textures[1] = noiseTexture;

            GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);

            // SpriteBatch.Begin will set the GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState to None.
            spriteBatch.Begin(
                    SpriteSortMode.Texture,
                    BlendState.AlphaBlend,
                    SamplerState.PointClamp,
                    null,
                    null,
                    scaleupEffect);
            spriteBatch.Draw(scaleupTarget, Vector2.Zero, null, Color.White, 0.0f, Vector2.Zero, upScaleAmount, SpriteEffects.None, 0.0f);            
            spriteBatch.End();

            // Set back to the original depthstate before you continue.
            GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that even though you tried to change the `DepthStencilState`, it still holds the key to your issue.

The process of calling `SpriteBatch.Begin()` turns off depth buffer test since it's not needed for the 2d rendering of the `SpriteBatch.Draw()` calls. Then the next frame, it's still turned off when you go to draw your 3d stuff and you get the problem you are experiencing.

So just before drawing 3d stuff, make sure your DepthStencilState is set back to `Default`.

```
GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.SeaGreen);

GraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.Opaque;
GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;            

DrawModel(building_a_mdl, (Matrix.Identity * Matrix.CreateTranslation(100, -14, -100)), building_a_tex);
```

See this link for reference: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/06/18/spritebatch-and-renderstates-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx

Comment: Still having the problem unfortunately, I took a screenshot and put it here: http://i39.tinypic.com/2chedu.png